# UICollectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath never called even though delegate is set

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionviewcell

I'm just trying to do a plain vanilla `UICollectionView` inside a `UIViewController`. Everything is working as desired except that nothing happens when I touch a `CollectionViewCell` to select it. Here's the bones of my code:

```
@interface CreateNewFieldViewController () <UITextFieldDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout>

- (void) viewDidLoad {
...
    UICollectionViewFlowLayout* flowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc]init];
    flowLayout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(self.width*.15, self.width*.15);
    [flowLayout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal];
    flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 30;
    flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 30;   

    self.collectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.width*.1, self.height*.2, self.width*.8, self.height*.3) collectionViewLayout:flowLayout];

    self.collectionView.delegate = self;
    self.collectionView.dataSource = self;

    self.collectionView.allowsSelection = YES;
    self.collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = NO;

    self.collectionView.bounces = YES;
    self.collectionView.alwaysBounceHorizontal = YES;
    self.collectionView.alwaysBounceVertical = YES;
    [self.collectionView registerClass:[CollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    [self.view addSubview:self.collectionView];

    self.collectionView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
...
}

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    self.fieldNameInput.text = self.backgroundImageNames[indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"recording this: %@", self.fieldNameInput.text);
}
```

The data source and flow layout work great, but for some reason when I click on a cell, nothing is happening. I don't see any log statements, so I know `didSelect` is not being called. What am I missing?

---

Looks like this may be a trap for the uninitiated, though I still can't find what it is. See e.g. this [blog post](http://adamtal.me/2014/10/26/is-my-uicollectionview-broken-yes-yes-it-is/).

Answer (score 1):

An extra call for the UICollectionView solves the problem:

```
[collectionView selectItemAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionNone];
```

And

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.selected = YES;
    [collectionView selectItemAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionNone];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion, but in my project it still produces no effect.